# Adjust title of bibliography frame

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I don't want the title of the bibliography slide to count.

So instead of having Bibliography I, Bibliography II, Bibliography III, Bibliography IV .... I want it to be just Bibliography regardless of how many frames are being used for the bibliographic references.

```
%%% ------------ BIBLIOGRAPHY ------------ %%%
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

% --- Use [ ] instead of ( )
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  
  
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{book}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvbook}}
    or test {\ifentrytype{collection}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvcollection}}
    or test {\ifentrytype{reference}} or test {\ifentrytype{mvreference}} }
    {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]}
    {\ifentrytype{online}
       {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[online]}
       {\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]}}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}
     {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\usebeamertemplate{bibliography item}}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

This is the result:

[image]
[image]

My wish is for it to remain just a Bibliography:

[image]
[image]

I'm inexperienced in LaTeX, but thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Please don't post only code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test document which we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `frametitle continuation` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{title}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```